# getting the number of elements in a struct

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct, sizeof

I have a struct:

```
struct KeyPair 
{ 
   int nNum;
   string str;  
};
```

Let's say I initialize my struct:

```
 KeyPair keys[] = {{0, "tester"}, 
                   {2, "yadah"}, 
                   {0, "tester"}
                  };
```

I would be creating several instantiations of the struct with different sizes. So for me to be able to use it in a loop and read it's contents, I have to get the number of elements in a struct. How do I get the number of elements in the struct? In this example I should be getting 3 since I initialized 3 pairs.

Comment: Why not use a std::map and you get all iterators to work with.

Comment: I think you want the number of elements in the array `keys`, right?

Comment: You want size of struct or size of the array? It is confusing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're trying to calculate the number of elements of the `keys` array you can simply do `sizeof(keys)/sizeof(keys[0])`.

The point is that the result of `sizeof(keys)` is the size in bytes of the keys array in memory.  This is not the same as the number of elements of the array, unless the elements are 1 byte long. To get the number of elements you need to divide the number of bytes by the size of the element type which is `sizeof(keys[0])`, which will return the size of the datatype of `key[0]`.

The important difference here is to understand that `sizeof()` behaves differently with arrays and datatypes. You can combine the both to achieve what you need.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof#Using_sizeof_with_arrays

Comment: sizeof does not return size in bytes.  sizeof(char) == 1   char could be 16-bits   eg Texas Instruments TMS320C54x DSP

Comment: @T33C:  sizeof *does* return size in bytes per the standard.  The C++ standard defines a "byte" as a char.  (This may not be the meaning of "byte" you are used to, but the standard is consistent.)

Answer (score 3):

```
sizeof(keys)/sizeof(*keys);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to count the elements of the array, you can make a macro

```
#define NUM_OF(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean the count of elements in `keys` ? In such a case you can use `int n = sizeof(keys)/sizeof(keys[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

In C++ it is generally not possible to do this. I suggest using std::vector.

The other solutions work in your specific case, but must be done at compile time. Arrays you new or malloc will not be able to use those tricks.

Comment: Yes it is always possible to count the number of elements in a C/C++ array by taking the size of the array and dividing by the size of the element. Perhaps the question was a bit confusingly put because Owen asked the size of struct instead of number of elements in array. But having looked at his previous post and his edit, number of elements is what he is after.

Answer (score 0):

> If you're trying to calculate the number of elements of the keys array
>   you can simply do sizeof(keys)/sizeof(keys[0]).

This can not be a general good solution, due to structure padding.

Comment: It doesn't matter what padding is present in KeyPair, this is a perfectly correct way to calculate the size of an array.